# Did I incorrectly close this question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I closed the following question (got closed directly because of my gold badge):

[Using Net.TCP WCF in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991701/using-net-tcp-wcf-in-iis)

which then was reopened by others.

The two questions did not look similar but I was quite sure that the answer would help as I had the same error several times.

The issue was also solved by the OP when he read the linked question (although he now got a new error).

Was I wrong to close it?

Comment: All reopen votes were cast in the reopen review queue: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4959060

Comment: in that case, should I vote close it again? Or will it just be reopened again?

Comment: You cannot vote anymore, you already used your vote.

Comment: Looks to me like the OP did the right thing, editing his question to emphasize his check-list to make it clear it wasn't a duplicate.  And picked up by other SO users to re-open it again.  This all went the way it is supposed to go.

Comment: doh! didn't see that it was reopened after the edit. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was re-opened [from the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4959060), after the OP [changed the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23991701/revisions#spacer-1c07145b-2f02-4280-a199-bd3d7bf9f134):

> I have follwed the links kindly supplied by people here.
>   the error I get (now) is:
>
> [image]
>
> (I cannot seem to enlarge this image with viewing in a different tab)

I guess the reviewers felt that the question had changed sufficiently that it could be reopened.  **It was not a judgement call on your close reason.** This was instead the normal procedure for a question that was edited after closing.

If you feel that the question is *still* a duplicate, you may want to try and solicit some help getting it closed again, in Chat perhaps. You already voted to close the post, you cannot vote on it again.